# bash divide result compared with float

Tags: bash, floating-point, divide

THis is part of my bash code;

```
        b=`cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'|wc -c`
        d=`cat 101127_2_aa_1.fastq|head -$a|tail -1|wc -c`
        if (($b%$d>=0.7))
        then
```

HOwever I got problems like:

```
line 13: ((: 26%100>=0.7: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".7")
```

WHat's the problem?
thx

edit: 
Two if loops in my script:

```
if (($a%4==0))
if (( 10*$b/$d>= 7 ))
```

Seems for first one, only "%" works

And for the second one, only "/" works

I'm confused

Comment: thx....but then what should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to get the modulo, or did you want to divide and messed up the operator? If modulo, then you better describe what you're doing, using modulo on floats... :) Your variable names do not help legibility. If it's division you wanted, then `($b*10)/$d>=7` should work.

Comment: yeah, division is my want. However, when using if (($a%4)),it works well. I mean "%" vs "/", which one should I use?

Comment: Well, division is `/`: `echo $((200/3))` gives `66`. `%` is modulo (remainder of division), so `echo $((200%3))` gives `2` (since 200 = 66 * 3 + 2). Both are *grammatical* in `bash`, but they do drastically different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division operator is `/`, not `%`.

Also bash does not have floats. The workaround is to do something like

```
if (( 10 * $b / $d >= 7 ))
```

or

```
if (( 10 * $b >= 7 * $d ))
```

Comment: I guess he wants the modulo operator... But judging from the code perhaps division is what he really wants. :)

Comment: yeah, division is what i want

Comment: However,about operator, when I do if (( $a%4==2 )), it works pretty much well. So "%" vs "/", ...I'm confused....

Comment: The modulo (%) gives the remainder of the division and will always be an integer.  Hence Bash will never complain.  The '/' operator is a division and can result in real (non-integer) values.

Comment: @JRFerguson - there are no real valued operations in bash. `if (( 4 / 3 == 5 /4 )) ; then echo there are no real valued operations in bash ; fi`

Comment: @mob : Yes, and that's a clever way to express it :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

BASH is a typeless programming language without floating-point arithmetic. However, you can do flotaing-point operations by using the **[bc](http://www.gnu.org/s/bc/)** tool. Following article nicely explains how: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/floating-point-math-bash . What you need from there is the `float_cond()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`.

Here are some examples.

```
[jaypal:~] awk 'BEGIN{ print 44/3 }'
14.6667

[jaypal:~] a=55
[jaypal:~] b=4
[jaypal:~] awk 'BEGIN { print '$a'/'$b' }'
13.75
```

As suggested by *@Amadan*, we can do something like this completely in `awk` -

```
a=44
b=5
c=$(awk 'BEGIN { print '$a'/'$b' }')
awk 'BEGIN{if ('$c'>.7) print "yeah"; else print "nope" }'
```

Comment: no it still doesn't work. Seems bash cannot directly compare anything with float (in this case, $c)...but still thanks a lot

Comment: If you're going to use `awk`, or `bc`, or `perl` or Ruby or anything external to `bash`, do the comparison there too, since `bash` can't handle the decimal point at all. The problem is not in the division (which is just imprecise) - the problem is in the `0.7` literal (and in your solution, `13.75` as well), which `bash` can't parse at all.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, I have changed my answer.